# Scrolling down with selenium on website not possible?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to scroll down on a website using selenium with the following code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  
  link = "https://unabated.com/mlb/odds"
  driver.get (link)   
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 20000)")     
  input("Press!") 
  driver.quit()
```

But when the site is opened the scroll down on the website is not happening?
How can i scroll down on this page?

Comment: `driver.quit()` or `driver.Quit()`? A suggested edit claimed the latter. What is correct?

Comment: I run it allways with driver.quit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is loaded async (and when first rows are loaded, bottom of the table is still not exist).

To load another rows of your table, you need to scroll to the last rendered row.

Executing scroll on load doesn't do anything, as far as table has not been rendered yet, so there is no scroll.

You need to implement continuous scroll to get bottom.

Logic is simple - you wait for all rows with selector `[ref=leftContainer] [role=row].ag-row-level-0` to exist, get the last row and scroll to it. Then you re-init rows array and check if last element is changed. If it is - repeat.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

link = "https://unabated.com/mlb/odds"
driver.get(link)
rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[ref=leftContainer] [role=row].ag-row-level-0')))
break_condition = False
while not break_condition:
    temp = rows[-1]
    actionChains.scroll_to_element(rows[-1]).perform()
    rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[ref=leftContainer] [role=row].ag-row-level-0')))
    if rows[-1] == temp:
        break_condition = True
```